# group cfdirectory by dateLastModified (date not time)

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9, cfdirectory

I am running ColdFusion 9 and Oracle database. I am trying to group all files from a directory by the `dateLastModified` using:

```
<cfdirectory action="LIST" 
    directory="#path_to_files#" 
    name="res" 
    sort="datelastmodified desc,name ASC" 
    filter="#filters#">
```

For example:

- Date of File 1: 2016-10-03 11:49:00 am
- Date of File 2: 2016-10-03 07:49:00 am
- Date of File 3: 2016-08-03 07:49:00 am

`File 1 & 2` should be group 1 and `File 3` should be group 2

If I use a query of query, how can I compare the date based on **days** not time? This is what I have so far but it does not seem to work. I get no records.

```
    <cfquery name="getfiles" dbtype="query">
        SELECT name, datelastmodified
        FROM   res
        WHERE  CAST( [datelastmodified] as date) = CAST(<cfqueryparam  cfsqltype="CF_SQL_DATE" value="#d#"/> as date)
    </cfquery>
```

Does anyone know a different method to group files based on days not time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured it out. Thanks to @Dan and @Leigh for their suggestion. I used both as guides to get what I wanted.

1. I used `cfdirectory` to get a query object.
2. I created a new query using `QueryNew`, `QueryAddRow` and `QuerySetCell`.
3. On the columns of the new query contained the formatted date (mm/dd/yyyy). Make sure that you declare the column as `varchar` not `date` when setting the column names `QueryNew`.
4. I used `cfloop` and `group` option and `cfoutput` to display the records.

   ```
   <cfset path_to_files = "d:\inetpub\wwwroot\mailrideli\webrpt\">
   <cfset filters = "*.pdf|*.txt|*.xls">
   <cfdirectory action="LIST" directory="#path_to_files#" name="res" sort="datelastmodified desc,name ASC" filter="#filters#">

   <cfset q = QueryNew("Name,dateformated,datelastmodified, size","Varchar, Varchar, date, varchar")>
   <cfset count = 1>
   <cfset newRow = QueryAddRow(q,res.recordCount)>

   <cfloop query="res">
       <cfset d = DateFormat(res.dateLastModified,"mm/dd/yyyy")>
       <cfset temp = QuerySetCell(q, "Name", "#res.name#", count)>
       <cfset temp = QuerySetCell(q, "dateformated", "#d#", count)>
       <cfset temp = QuerySetCell(q, "datelastmodified", "#res.datelastmodified#", count)>
   <cfset temp = QuerySetCell(q, "size", "#res.size#", count)>

   <cfset count += 1>
   </cfloop>

   <cfoutput>
       <cfloop query="q" group="dateformated">
                       #q.dateformated#<br />


                       <table>
                           <tr>
                               <th>File Name</th>
                               <th>Size (bytes)</th>
                               <th>Last Modified</th>
                           </tr>
                           <cfloop>

                               <tr>
                                   <td><a href="#q.name#">#q.name#</a></td>
                                   <td>#q.size#</td>
                                   <td>#dateformat(q.dateLastModified, 'mm/dd/yyyy')# #timeformat(q.dateLastModified, 'hh:mm:ssTT')#</td>
                               </tr>

                           </cfloop>
                       </table>
       </cfloop>
       </cfoutput>
   ```

I hope it helps anyone out there.

Comment: (Edit) *created a new query* Any particular reason? :) Unless I am misunderstanding, a manual query is not necessary. If you run [the first QoQ here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39837141/104223), it produces the same results, with a bit less code. Side note, since the goal is output, no for cfloop. Just use nested cfoutput tags.

Answer (score 2):

> method to group files based on days not time

To group by Date (only), add the "date only" column to your SELECT list. Then ORDER BY the new column:

```
<cfquery name="qSortedFiles" dbtype="query">
    SELECT CAST(DateLastModified AS Date) AS DateOnly
            , Name
            , DateLastModified 
    FROM   getFiles
    ORDER BY DateOnly
</cfquery>

<cfoutput query="qSortedFiles" group="DateOnly">
    #DateOnly#<br>
    <cfoutput>
        - #DateLastModified#<br>
    </cfoutput>
</cfoutput>
```

> I get no records.

FWIW, the reason is that despite using `CAST ... as Date`, apparently CF still preserves the "time" portion internally. So the `WHERE` clause is still comparing apples and oranges:

```
  <!--- comparing Date and Time to Date (only)
  WHERE 2016-08-03 07:49:00 am  = 2016-08-03 00:00:00 am
```

Instead of using an equals comparison, use this approach:

```
    WHERE DateLastModified >= {TheStartDateAtMidnight}
    AND   DateLastModified < {TheNextDayAtMidnight}
```

This type of comparison is more flexible as it works with both date and time columns - and dates (only).

```
WHERE  CAST(DateLastModified AS Date) >= <cfqueryparam value="#someDate#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_date">
AND    CAST(DateLastModified AS Date)  < <cfqueryparam value="#dateAdd('d', 1, someDate)#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_date">
```

Answer (score 1):

Step 1 - Use cfdirectory to get a query object.

Step 2 - Add a column using queryaddcolumn.

Step 3 - Loop through the query.  Use querySetCell and dateformat on your new column

Step 4 - use cfoutput, group by your new column, to do what you need to do.  Your cfdirectory tag already has the data sorted.